# Waiting on tasks from different Executors

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have certain logical operations separated into different tasks running concurrently on different java.util.concurrent.Executors.

For all tasks in an operation, I'd like to be notified once each one completes (i.e, a notification once all are done is not enough in this case).

Is there an implementation of java.util.concurrent.CompletionService which can wait and provide task results from more than one Executor? Would this even be possible?

My current (not perfect) solution is a queue of tasks being taken from the CompletionService by the order of their submission. A proprietary solution using listeners is also possible, though I would prefer to use java.util.concurrent if at all possible.

Edit: I eventually did as suggested by Greg except I extended FutureTask instead of Runnable.

Comment: CountDownLatch + a collection of FutureTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could just wrap your Executors with an entity that knows of the CompletionService's Queue.

i.e.

```
public class MyCompletionService implements Executor /* optional implements CompletionService too */ {
      private final Executor mExecutor;
      private Queue<Runnable> mRunnableQueue;

      public MyNotifyingExecutorWrapper (Queue<Runnable> queueToNotify, Executor wrapped) {
             mExecutor = wrapped;
             mRunnableQueue = queueToNotify;
      }


      public execute(Runnable command) {
             mExecutor.execute(new NotifyingRunnable(command, mRunnableQueue));
      }

      private static class NotifyingRunnable implements Runnable {
            private final Queue<Runnable> mRunnables;
            private Runnable mRunnable;

            public NotifyingRunnable(Runnable runnable, Queue<Runnable> done) {
                 mRunnables = done;
                 mRunnable = runnable;
            }
            public void run() {
                  mRunnable.run();
                  mRunnables.add(mRunnable);
            }
      }
  }
```

You could make this class implements CompletionExecutorService and choose one instance to take/poll from (assuming all your instances use the same queue), or just create a consumer of the queue in a more raw sense.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
         private MyCompletionService[] executors = ... {} ;

         while(true){
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: Woohoo %s is done!", System.currentTimeMillis(), queue.take()));
         }
   }
```

}

**Note** omitted Exception handling and actual implicit code of executing the individual tasks :)

Comment: What guarantee is there that the Runnable is done once the take() removes it from the queue?

Comment: Well the thread of execution would execute Runnable.run(), when that completes, it will just add the completed runnable to the queue of completed tasks. Not sure what guarantee you are looking for as all Runnables can be executed again (from an api level that is). I would recommend a blocking queue for the situation you are trying to model. That way when there is something that is completed, the take() call will unblock.

Comment: You are of course right. However, this solution would not be ideal for handling Callables as well as Runnables. I would prefer to find a solution managing it with Futures.

Comment: Probably could just replace the Runnables returned with Future<Void> then. However you would have no way of knowing which Runnable/Callable produced which future.